# Create more than one label to a single relation in cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Currently i am working with graph db. I have two nodes and i need to create more than one label to the same relation. Is it possible to create more than one label to a relationship in cypher query? 
I tried this, but not working:

```
START n=node(1), n1=node(2) CREATE UNIQUE (n)-[r:HAS_TEST:HAS_ATTENDED]->(n1) return n,n1;
```

If it is possible, how? If it is not possible why?

Comment: BTW unless you're on an old release of neo4j, the start clause has been deprecated http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.5/query-start.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A relationship has a single type, so you cannot do what you've asked. Instead, create two relationships:

```
START n=node(1), n1=node(2)
CREATE UNIQUE (n)-[:HAS_TEST]->(n1)
CREATE UNIQUE (n)-[:HAS_ATTENDED]->(n1)
RETURN n,n1;
```

Or create a new relationship type that implies both `HAS_TEST` and `HAS_ATTENDED`.

Comment: Thanks @Luanne .. I just need to reduce one relationship by doing so. Thats what i tried.. But its ok...